# Bootstrap logo isn't responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

If I shrink my screen size, the logo will either be very small and work on mobile phones or very large and work on desktops and looks BLURRY. How can I get the logo to be fluent on all screen sizes, including tablets? The logo size is 793 x 150 pixels, it is a wide logo. This size is just what is uploaded on the server, of course it is a lot smaller on the actual site so it fits in the navbar.

The logo is added in HTML like this:

```html
<a class=navbar-brand href=http://example.com/><img src="http://example.com/resources/imgs/logo.png" alt="Example"></a>
```

CSS:

```css
header .navbar-brand {
    padding-top: 7px;
    padding-bottom: 7px
}
header .navbar-brand>img {
    height: 46px
}
header .navbar-brand>img {
        height: auto;
        width: 135px
}
```

Comment: where is your code.!

Comment: Do you want to see the CSS?

Comment: add class="img-responsive" in image tag

Comment: Your snippet is not useful. Please create a better one having a look at https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add the `img-responsive` class to `img` tag. And set a specific width to anchor tag if needed.**

```
<a class=navbar-brand href=http://example.com/><img src="http://example.com/resources/imgs/logo.png" alt="Example" class="img-responsive"></a>
```

**CSS:**

```
.navbar-brand {
   max-width: 60px;
}
```

The class `img-responsive` applies `max-width: 100%;, height: auto; and display: block;` to the image so that it scales nicely to the parent element.

Read more about it here:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive

Looking at your site do the following changes:

**Remove codes from**

custom.css line 699

```
header .navbar-brand > img {
   height: 200px;
}
```

style.css 5105

```
.navbar-brand > img {
    display: block;
}
```

Use this:

style.css 2091

```
.navbar-brand {
    float: left;
    padding: 12px 15px;
    font-size: 19px;
    line-height: 21px;
    height: 62px;
    max-width: 200px;
    display: table;
}
```

Edit the html:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="http://soldmymac.com/"><span><img src="http://soldmymac.com/resources/imgs/logo.png" alt="Sold My Mac" class="img-responsive"></span></a>
```

And add the css:

```
.navbar-brand span {
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle; // This will keep the logo vertically in the middle
}
```

And one last thing....

**LEARN CSS IF YOU GOT TIME. IT IS EASY.**

Comment: Thanks, I will add that. I have added the CSS rules I am using in here, please have a look and let me know if those are needed. The logo is pretty big because it is wide, so I just want it to look nice and crisp on all screen sizes.

Comment: As I have written in answer, remove all height and width styles from img tag. Just add the class. and then add max-width to navbar-brand

Comment: Ok, should I remove the other navbar-brand CSS style rules?

Comment: Depends on how you want your layout. If you are using the rules I have said above the image should look fine

Comment: My CSS file is a huge mess.

Comment: May be you can share your URL

Comment: s o l d m y m a c .com

Comment: I really appreciate all of the help you provided, saved me another headache. Have a good night.

Comment: Glad I could help

Comment: To make the logo a bit bigger, I would edit the code in style.css?

Comment: Just increase the max-width for navbar-brand

Comment: Ok great, do you suggest Bootstrap is what I should learn first?

Comment: Learn CSS first. If you are good with CSS then go for bootstrap

Comment: Please can you remove the site URL and screenshot from your answer.